# update column values with call to javascript function using knex update

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I'm anonymising data using knex migrations. I'm using the faker library to generate random street names that will replace the real street names. I need the knex update statement to call the faker.address.streetAddress() function as it would call any other mysql function ( RAND() for example ).

The workaround I have found is significantly less performant.

```js
const faker = require("faker/locale/de");

exports.up = function (knex) {
  // generate a random character in the set ('A', 'B', 'C')
  return knex("Address").update(
    "street",
    knex.raw("CHAR(FLOOR( 65 + RAND( ) *3 ))")
  );
  // alternative is not very performant
  return knex("Address")
    .pluck("id")
    .then(function (ids) {
      return Promise.all(
        ids.map((id) =>
          knex("Address")
            .where({ id: id })
            .update({ street: faker.address.streetAddress() })
        )
      );
    });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One just cannot call backend's javascript functions from SQL server side to generate data.

If you want to randomize every street name in a single query with a different value, you cannot use faker (or any other javascript side library), but you need to generate the fake address on DB side (like you do with first rand() example).

That can be done for example by creating an SQL procedure for address generation and use it instead of faker. Probably the address generator is pretty easy to write by using some predefined word lists and randomizing names from those + adding some street number etc.